# Step through wordpress code

Tags: php

I was wondering if anybody knew how to setup step through code for Wordpress. I have tried [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/index.php) but had no luck setting it up on my VPS. I managed to get it working on my localhost at one stage but it didn't track WP too well in conjunction with NetBeans. It either tried to load my page without the core WP files or lost track of what was going on before I could navigate to the page I wanted to debug.

To config my xdebug install I followed all the instructions on http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php but NetBeans could not talk to my remote testing server.

For those interested here is the `phpinfo()` output post xdebug install: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dFgndG42)

*tried to make this community wiki as I feel it's appropriate but the checkbox turned up absent*

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit for a wiki ... but once answers start coming in I might change my mind.

Comment: I agree, Netbeans/WP/Xdebug all play nice, but this question relates to netbeans and/or Xdebug.

Comment: I have only had netbeans and xdebug working nicely with non-wp sites and on local and i would prefer to test on a remote host. I am wondering how to configure it so it will follow to and/or load the page I want inside of WP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the same as what you want, but perhaps this plugin might be of some help?

[WordPress Hook Sniffer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-hook-sniffer/)

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. I was looking for something that is roughly equivalent to http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express (Microsoft Visual Web Developer)as the plugin I am making for my client is largely independent of wordpress so I wanted to run it on a line by line basis.